# User authentication with Google accounts fails with webapp2 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

My app have stopped to work a few days ago for customers that use their Google account to connect.
Even the helloworld.py example (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers) do not work anymore and generates a Server error outside of my app (no log):

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

Here is the code for the helloworld.py I used :

> from google.appengine.api import users
>
> import webapp2
>
> class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>
> ```
> def get(self):
>     # Checks for active Google account session
>     user = users.get_current_user()
>
>     if user:
>         self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>         self.response.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
>     else:
>         self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
> ```
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>       ('/', MainPage), ], debug=True
>   )

Any idea why?
It fails once redirected to the URL created by users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)

Comment: The helloworld.py doesn't work in development? Have you updated your code somehow prior to the problem?

Comment: helloworld.py works on on dev server but no more on production. Linked to OpenID deprecation? If so I'm wondering why the doc is still online? Each time I use users.create_login_url, that makes Google server fail (on Prod).

Comment: You'd need to inspect and share the server-side logs for your app using the Log Viewer. You should find a stacktrace that can explain the root-cause of the errors.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging

Comment: My app's log is empty the crash is not coming from my app but Google authentication server (which I don't have access to the logs!)